# How to declare a variable depends on another in Angular 8

Tags: angular

Updated stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/github/Cheong-LiJie/student-program

I am new in Angular 8 and I am coding a college project which user can register student and professor.

I have 2 interface which are Student and Professor and each professor is handling different subject and if the student is taking IT subject then his professor will be A, if he is taking Account then his professor will be B.

The only way that I can think is create an if..else statement like

```
if (student.subject == IT){
   student.professor == Dr. Kenny
}else {
   student.professor == Dr. John
}
```

But this is just hard-code and every time I add a new professor and subject I need to modify the code again.  How can I declare the student.professor depends on professor.subject and student.subject?

College.ts:

```
export interface IStudent{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  age:number;
  subject:string;
  education:string;
  professor:string;
}

export interface IProfessor{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  faculty:string;
  subject:string;
}
```

in-memory-data.service.ts

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService{

  createDb() {
    var students = [
  {"id":1,"name":"John","age":22,"subject":"IT","education":"Diploma"},
  {"id":2,"name":"Austine","age":26,"subject":"Business","education":"Degree"},
  {"id":3,"name":"Samantha","age":24,"subject":"Account","education":"Diploma"},
  {"id":4,"name":"Lily","age":25,"subject":"IT","education":"Degree"},
  {"id":5,"name":"Ken","age":19,"subject":"Account","education":"Diploma"},
    ];

    var professors = [
      {  "id":1, "name":"Dr. Lim","faculty":"FOCS","subject":"IT"},
      {  "id":2, "name":"Professor Anthony","faculty":"FASC","subject":"Account"},
      {  "id":3, "name":"Ms. Pua","faculty":"FAFB","subject":"Business"}
    ];
    return {students,professors};
  }
```

studentList.html

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Programme</th>
      <th>Education</th>
      <th>Professor</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr *ngFor="let student of students">
      <a routerLink="/student-detail/{{ student.id }}">
        <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
      </a>
      <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.age }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.subject }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.education }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.professor }}</td>
    <td>
```

student.component.ts

```
export class StudentListComponent implements OnInit {
  students: IStudent[];
  public successMsg: string;
  public popoverTitle : string = 'Confirmation Dialog';
  public popoverMessage : string = 'Are you sure you want to delete this student?';
  public confirmClicked : boolean = false;
  public cancelClicked : boolean = false;

  @ViewChild(StudentDetailComponent) child;

  constructor(
    private _studentService: StudentService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._studentService
      .getStudents()
      .subscribe(data => (this.students = data));

    this.successMsg = this.child.successMsg;
  }


  delete(student: IStudent): void {
    this.students = this.students.filter(s => s !== student);
    this._studentService
      .delete(student)
      .subscribe(
        data =>
          (this.successMsg = "You have deleted student with ID " + student.id)
      );
  }

  private loadAllUsers() {
    this._studentService.getStudents().subscribe(students => {
      this.students = students;
    });
  }
}
```

student.service.ts:

```
export class StudentService {
  private _url = "api/students";

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) {}

  delete(student: IStudent | number): Observable<IStudent> {
    const id = typeof student === "number" ? student : student.id;
    const url = `${this._url}/${id}`;

    return this._http.delete<IStudent>(url);
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`StudentService: ${message}`);
  }

  getStudents(): Observable<IStudent[]> {
    return this._http.get<IStudent[]>(this._url);
  }

  getStudent(id: number): Observable<IStudent> {
    const url = `${this._url}/${id}`;
    return this._http.get<IStudent>(url);
  }

  addStudent(student: IStudent): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post<any>(this._url, student);
  }
  updateStudent(student: IStudent): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.put<any>(this._url, student);
  }
}
```

Comment: is student assigned to only one professor? OR is there only one professor for a unique subject ==> student will select only one subject and will be assigned to a single professor?

Comment: @MilanLakhani Yes, one student will assign to only one professor. Every professor is handling unique subject, student can only select one subject then will be assigned to specific professor that handle the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the idea is "cache" the profesors (profesors will be a few profesors)

profesor.service

```
professors:IProfessor[]=null;
 getProfessors(): Observable<IProfessor[]> {
    return this.professors? of(this.professors):
      this._http.get<IProfessor[]>(this._url).pipe(
         tap(res=>{
            this.professors=res;
         })
      ); 
  }
```

Then, in student.service, you can change the getStudents and getStudent to get the profesor

```
getStudents(): Observable<IStudent[]> {
    return forkJoin(this._professorService.getProfessors(),this._http.get<IStudent[]>(this._url)).pipe(
    map(([professors,students]:[IProfessor[],IStudent[]])=>{
       students.forEach(x=>{
          const professor=professors.find(p=>p.subject==x.subject)
          x.professor=professor 
          //you can also only get the name, e.g.
          //x.profesorName=profesor?profesor.name:''
       })
       return students
    })
  )
  }

getStudent(id: number): Observable<IStudent> {
    const url = `${this._url}/${id}`;
    return forkJoin(this._professorService.getProfessors(),
                    this._http.get<IStudent>(url)).pipe(
    map(([professors,student]:[IProfessor[],IStudent])=>{
          const professor=professors.find(p=>p.subject==student.subject)
          student.professor=professor 
          //you can also only get the name, e.g.
          //student.profesorName=profesor?profesor.name:''
         return student
    })
    )
  }
```

Comment: I get this error ```Type 'IStudent[]' is not assignable to type 'IProfessor[]'.
  Property 'faculty' is missing in type 'IStudent' but required in type 'IProfessor'.``` on this line ```tap(res=>{
            this.professors=res;
         }```

Comment: I forgot in tap put the types `tap((res:IProfesor[])=>{this.professors=res}`, be carefully, in getStudents I forgot also a ] in `map([profesors,student]:[IProfesor[],IStudent[])`

Comment: I still getting error from the code, btw I have updated Stackblitz link in my question can you help me to try the code in Stackblitz if you dont mind. Thank

Comment: sorry for multiple sintax errors, just corrected in code, you can see in https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-shwrwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstudent.service.ts NOTE: There error but not in services, I add a line in the functions: getStudents and getStudent  `,tap(res=>{console.log(res)})` in stackblitz that you can remove (it's only to check the response)

Answer (score 4):

> How can I declare the student.professor depends on professor.subject and student.subject?

You have set your interfaces up in what is known as a denormalised way. By that, I mean you are storing information about a unique entity across multiple entities.

In your domain you have at least the following entity concepts:

- student
- professor
- subject

Subject and student (as things stand) have a one-to-many relationship. One subject can have many students. One student can have one subject.

Subject and professor have a one-to-one relationship. One subject can have one professor. One professor can have one subject (I assume).

#### The design

Subject has one property - its name. Professors have many properties. You could store the subject on the professor and the professor object on the student.

```
export interface IStudent{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  age:number;
  education:string;
  professor: IProfessor;
}

export interface IProfessor{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  faculty:string;
  subject:string;
}
```

Then you get the student's subject via the professor:

```
const subject = student.professor.subject;
```

#### Treating the subject as an object

Alternatively, you could treat the subject as an object. It is also common to store the id of a complex object and then look it up when you need it.

```
export interface IStudent{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  age:number;
  education:string;
  subjectId: number;
}

export interface IProfessor{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  faculty:string;
}

export interface ISubject{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  professorId: number;
}
```

You would add unique entities for each entity (within each entity array), and then lookup an entity when you need it.

For example:

```
const student = this.service.getStudent(1);
const subject = this.service.getSubject(student.subjectId);
const professor = this.service.getProfessor(subject.professorId);
```

Where the service methods are some optimised way of finding an entity by its id.

#### How to choose a design?

There is never just one choice to make when choosing a design. Which one you choose depends on how it best suits your needs. This is not only true in the entity design, but also how you store it. If you have 1000 students and a lot of queries, you don't want to be searching the whole array every time just to find a student by their id.

Comment: Why need to create a professor variable in the IProfessor interface? what is the data should be for the professor?

Comment: Updated answer. I didn't mean to add the `professor` property to `IProfessor`

Comment: Thank you, your answer and explanation is very clear!

Comment: I declared this ```const subject = this.student.professor.subject;``` in the ```ngOnInit()``` in student-list.component.ts but the problem is I don't know how to read the value of subject.  Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you create a simple demo https://stackblitz.com/ to show what you have so far

Comment: Updated the link in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `if` statement, you could do a search by the subject on the professors array. Something like this will assign the first professor of the subject,

```
const professor = professors.find(p => p.subject === student.subject);
student.professor = professor ? professor.name : null;
```